Pauli Twirling not increasing Circuit depth?
This paper talks about the properties of Pauli twirling a circuit. Pauli twirling is a technique that converts arbitrary quantum noise into Pauli errors by applying random Pauli gates before and after quantum operations.
The paper claims that "Randomized coupling (RC) creates a set of randomized circuits that are logically equivalent to the original bare circuit, without increasing circuit depth" and I'm trying to understand how the circuit depth won't increase. For example, twirling a circuit with CNOT gates in it should change the depth of the circuit right? Any help is appreciated!
Update: I believe the depth can be kept constant through a compilation pass, but otherwise, the additional single-qubit gates increase the circuit depth.

@MarkSpinelli Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the post now and will follow that next time too.

In randomized compiling, Pauli twirling is performed by replacing the "easy" gate with a new gate:
$$
C_k \mapsto T_k C_k T^c_{k-1},
$$
chosen so that the circuit is equivalent to the original circuit. Specifically, if the "hard" gates are Clifford and $T_k$ are Paulis, by pulling the $T^\dagger_{k-1}$ through the hard gate, we will get another Pauli, $T^c_{k-1}$, which cancels the effect of $T_{k-1}$. Assuming we can perform all easy gates and their product with Paulis (and choosing the first and the last $T$ to be identity), the total depth doesn't change.
